# issue with creating multiple leaflet layers from one geojson file

Tags: leaflet

I have included my code below.  While it is sort of working, ill get to that in a minute, I feel like there is a better, more efficient, more correct, way to achieve my goal.  I have a map for different weather options, in this case, Tornado, Severe Weather and Flash flood warnings.  These are all included in one geojson file.  The geo json file has a property called LayerId.  This determines the time in the loop that the layer would show.  I have a simple global map loop that constantly runs from 0 - 11.  So if I am on loop 5, then only the data that corresponds with LayerId 5 would be visible.  All others would be hidden/removed (which ever is preferred).  When the loop hits 6, the layer corresponding to LayerId 5 would go away and LayerId 6 would now show and so on.  Once the loop reaches 11, it starts over at 0.

I am not using a leaflet control due to the site requirements so i am using my own simple check box controls.  when the check box is clicked, it calls a toggleLayer function to apply filters to my data.  If FlashFlood is checked then only the data corresponding to the flash flood would show over the course of the loop IF it has data for flash flood at that interval.

When i said that it is sort of working...in my loop function i have a call to remove a layer.  this works except every now and then it throws a null or undefined error.  problem is is that its never the same layer.  each time i start the application, its a different layer that errors out.

Below i have included a sample of my geojson and the code.  The entry point for the code is at the toggleLayer function.

Thanks for any and all help.

**GEOJSON FILE**

```
{
   "name": "WarningsJson",
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [ -86.00, 31.00 ],
            [ -86.00, 32.00 ],
            [ -87.00, 30.00 ],
            [ -86.00, 31.00 ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": null,
        "strokeColor": "#ff9aa3",
        "StartDateTime": "09/29/2020 7:30:00 AM",
        "EndDateTime": "09/29/2020 9:30:00 AM",
        "strokeThickness": 20,
        "InfoboxTitle": "SFFW",
        "Station": "KMOB",
        "Identifier": "FFW",
        "LayerId": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [ -87.00, 32.00 ],
            [ -87.00, 33.00 ],
            [ -88.00, 31.00 ],
            [ -87.00, 32.00 ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": null,
        "strokeColor": "#c0ffd4",
        "StartDateTime": "09/29/2020 7:30:00 AM",
        "EndDateTime": "09/29/2020 9:30:00 AM",
        "strokeThickness": 2,
        "InfoboxTitle": "TOR",
        "Station": "KMOB",
        "Identifier": "TOR",
        "LayerId": "1"
      }
    },......
```

**APPLICATION CODE**

```
 var WarnStormModel = (function () {

        var layer0 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer1 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer2 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer3 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer4 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer5 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer6 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer7 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer8 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer9 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer10 = new L.LayerGroup();
        var layer11 = new L.LayerGroup();

        var warnConditionsLayersGroup = [layer0, layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer5, layer6, layer7, layer8, layer9, layer10, layer11];

        var tornadoActive = false;
        var svrActive = false;
        var ffwActive = false;

        const WarnFilter = {
            tornado: null,
            svr: null,
            flood: null
        }

        function init() {

            $.getJSON('/Data/GeoJsonFiles/WarningJsons/Warnings_0.json', function (data) {
                L.geoJSON(data, {
                    style: function (feature) {
                        return {
                            color: feature.properties.strokeColor,
                            fillOpacity: 0
                        };
                    },
                    pane: "warnPane",
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                        var popupText = '<div>'
                            + '<span style="float: right; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand"</i></span><br>'
                            + '<b>LAYER:  </b>' + layer.feature.properties.LayerId + '<br>'
                            + '<b>TYPE:  </b>' + layer.feature.properties.InfoboxTitle + '<br>'
                            + '<b>STATION:</b>' + layer.feature.properties.Station + '<br>'
                            + '<b>START:  </b>' + layer.feature.properties.StartDateTime + '<br>'
                            + '<b>END:  </b>' + layer.feature.properties.EndDateTime + '<br>';

                        layer.bindPopup(popupText);
                        layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.LayerId;

                        if (feature.properties.LayerId == "0") { layer0.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "1") { layer1.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "2") { layer2.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "3") { layer3.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "4") { layer4.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "5") { layer5.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "6") { layer6.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "7") { layer7.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "8") { layer8.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "9") { layer9.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "10") { layer10.addLayer(layer); }
                        else if (feature.properties.LayerId == "11") { layer11.addLayer(layer); }


                    },
                    filter: function (feature, layer) {
                        return (
                            feature.properties.Identifier === WarnFilter.tornado ||
                            feature.properties.Identifier === WarnFilter.svr ||
                            feature.properties.Identifier === WarnFilter.flood
                        )
                    },
                    interactive: true
                });
            }).fail(function (err) { console.log('createWarningsErr: ', err); })
        };

        //**********//
        function isActive(layer) {
            if (layer == "TOR") { return tornadoActive; }
            else if (layer == "SVR") { return tstrmActive; }
            else if (layer == "FFW") { return ffwActive; }
        }

        var isAnyActive = function () { return tornadoActive || svrActive || ffwActive; }

        var toggleLayer = function (layer, checkState) {

            switch (layer) {
                case "TOR": (checkState) ? WarnFilter.tornado = 'TOR' : WarnFilter.tornado = null; tornadoActive = !tornadoActive;
                    break;
                case "SVR": (checkState) ? WarnFilter.svr = 'SVR' : WarnFilter.svr = null; svrActive = !svrActive;
                    break;
                case "FFW": (checkState) ? WarnFilter.flood = 'FFW' : WarnFilter.flood = null; ffwActive = !ffwActive;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (checkState) {
                        for (key in WarnFilter) {
                            if (WarnFilter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                debugger
                                WarnFilter[key] = (key.toString()).toUpperCase();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //set all values in filter themselves to show
                    else {
                        for (key in WarnFilter) {
                            if (WarnFilter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                WarnFilter[key] = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            
            showHide(layer, checkState);
        }

        //**********//

        var showHide = function (layer, checkState) {
            rerender();
            if (isAnyActive() && checkState) {
                warnConditionsLayersGroup[GlobalMapLoop.getLoopIndex()].addTo(getMap());
            }
            else {
                warnConditionsLayersGroup[GlobalMapLoop.getLoopIndex()].removeLayer(getMap());
            }
        }

        var loop = function (currentIndex, pastIndex) {
            console.log("got to warn loop", currentIndex, pastIndex, isAnyActive())

            if (isAnyActive()) {
                
                getMap().removeLayer(warnConditionsLayersGroup[pastIndex]);
                getMap().addLayer(warnConditionsLayersGroup[currentIndex]);
            }
        }

        var rerender = (function () {
            init();
        })

        return {
            init: init,
            toggleLayer: toggleLayer,
            loop: loop,
            rerender: rerender
        };
    })();
```

Comment: Overriding `_leaflet_id` with your own arbitrary value is likely to create bugs. It is used internally by Leaflet for more things than just consumer app Layers.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!   on a side note, see any way to improve my code?